# Failed an audit due to a misclick and am now temporarily suspended from reviews

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review-audits

I was doing some reviews on StackOverflow, and failed an audit due to a misclick. Now I have to wait a couple of days before doing any more. Has the threshold changed from more than one failure to 1 failure?

Comment: I'm sure you could find plenty of other things to do for a couple of days. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

You failed [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2224115) a few days ago.

**Slow down.**

It's a lot easier to click the right buttons when you do.